# RecyclerView Data Update During Async Filtering

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm using [`Filter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter) in my [`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) . And the adapter data is updated every 30 seconds. The filtering process is handled in a background thread. If the dataset changes during filtering (ex: Last 10 items are removed) it can cause problems. How can I prevent that from happening? I thought about waiting for the filtering process to finish but it will stall the UI thread.

```java
    public class ElevatorsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElevatorsAdapter.ElevatorViewHolder> implements Filterable {

        private final ArrayList<Elevator> elevators;

        public ElevatorsAdapter() {
            this.elevators = new ArrayList<>(dataStore.getElevatorList());
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ElevatorsAdapter.ElevatorViewHolder holder, int position) {
            Elevator elevator = elevators.get(position);
            holder.textViewRow.setText(elevator.getDisplay());
        }

        public void update() { //This is called to update the adapter.
            elevators = dataStore.getElevatorList();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return elevators.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return filter;
        }

        private final Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                List<Elevator> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    filtered = new ArrayList<>(dataStore.getElevatorList());
                } else {
                    String pattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                    for (Elevator e : dataStore.getElevatorList()) {
                        if (e.getDisplay().toLowerCase().contains(pattern)) {
                            filtered.add(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                results.values = filtered;
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, @NonNull FilterResults results) {
                elevators = (ArrayList<Elevator>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: We need to see some code.

Comment: Ok, I added the relevant parts.

Comment: post the error message. The one from Logcat

Comment: It's not ready to test yet. But I know two different threads working on the same ArrayList can cause problems. And I cant find any solution.

Comment: What problems is it causing?  Are you crashing?  Seeing glitches?  Something else?  You shouldn't actually be executing on the same array on both threads, as the UI component doesn't get to access the filtered array (which is in a new arraylist) until after the filtering is done, and after that the filtering isn't accessing that list.

Comment: The filtering thread is accessing the main list to add elements to the filtered list. But meanwhile main list is updated every 30 seconds. If one of this updates happens when the main list was iterating by filtering thread it will probably crash.